# issues regarding math.rounding

Tags: c#

I have two values who "user" put in

double = x

uint = y

x + y

How do i write the code for rounding up value x + y with my conditions and adding them together? ?.

if  x+y = <0.25 round to 0 if  x+y = 0.25-0.75 round to 0.5
if  x+y = >0.75 round to 1

Example. X = 199,45 - Y = 122,30 = 77,15.
This should then be rounded to 77 because its decimal is below 0.25

I am writing a program for a cash machine for a school project.
X has to be a uint and y has to be a double ?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. If you can't get started, ask your instructor for help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Also, `y = 122.30` can never happen, because `uint` is an integer, and integers don't have fractional values. You should review your notes on C# data types.

Comment: Sorry for not reading through the guide lines, my program is already finished. 

The thing I am only stuck on is how to make these conditions into my written program.
My instructor is not fluent in our native language which makes it very difficult to communicate with him, also he wants us to find out the answers ourselves but I've read almost everything but couldnt find anything to explain what i am doing, therefore my question Should I post my whole program so you guys can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own extension to handle rounding

```
public static class DoubleHelper {
    public static double MyRounding(this double x)
    {
        var decimals = x - Math.Floor(x);
        if (decimals < 0.25) decimals = 0;
        else if (decimals >= 0.25 && decimals <= 0.75) decimals = 0.5;
        else decimals = 1;
        return Math.Floor(x) + decimals;
    }
}
```

then use it

```
double x = 199.76;
uint y = 122;
Console.WriteLine((x - y).MyRounding()); // 78
x = 199.75;
Console.WriteLine((x - y).MyRounding()); // 77.5
x = 199.25;
Console.WriteLine((x - y).MyRounding()); // 77.5
x = 199.24;
Console.WriteLine((x - y).MyRounding()); // 77
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: As above commenter said i cannot have y as uint.

Right now i have
double payment; 
double paymentmade;

payment = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
paymentmade= double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

how do i add these to an uint ?